# Trying to run HADOOP 2.8.0; localhost refused to connect

Tags: hadoop

I have done the  complete installation of hadoop 2.8.0 without any ambiguity but when i tried to run the localhost:8088 it doesn't get the results.

Below is the message:

> This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Please show output of jps and add your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml

Comment: Also, why an old version of Hadoop?